# how to get value of first column in a html table on clicking on row

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a simple html table. I want to get the value of first column of a row on which i click.
if i click on first row anywhere it should get value of 1st column of 1st row ,if i click on 2nd row anywhere, it should give value of 1st column of second row..
here is my table:

```
<table style="border:1px solid black" id="tab">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-right:1px solid black">Sachin</td>
        <td>Yuvraj</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-right:1px solid black">Virat</td>
        <td>Gautam</td>              
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you made your own research?

Comment: please post the problematic code.

Comment: problematic code is so big ..i just need elementry idea. i will apply that in my real code

Comment: i have tried this :- var data= $('table tr:first td:first').text(); but it gives value of 1st column of 1st row only it does not deal with click event

Comment: see my answer, you just use the onClick attribute - then you can run whatever javascript you want.

Comment: problem solved..thanks everybody :- <tr onClick="alert($(this).find('td:first').text())">
  ...
</tr>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    //use this if you have jquery version 1.7+
      $('table#tab tr').on('click',function(){
          alert($(this).find('td:first').text());

    });
    //normal way
  $('table#tab tr').click(function(){
          alert($(this).find('td:first').text());

    });
//delegation

$('body').delegate('table#tab tr','click',function(){
          alert($(this).find('td:first').text());

    });

//use any of these three methods

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<tr onClick="alert($(this).find('td:first').text())">
  ...
</tr>
```

Basically, onClick runs javascript when the row is clicked.

---

Or to make jQuery attach the event after page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table#tab tr').on('click',function() {
    alert($(this).find('td:first').text());
  });
});
```

Comment: your logic is looking absolutly right but still not working. by the way thanks indeed for your help

Comment: this is the way to write the .first() method.

Comment: there was a little bug in your code...just use this instead :-onClick="alert($(this).find('td:first').text())"  thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you. Try this..

```
<tr onClick="alert($(this).find('td:first').text())">
  ...
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mark up is as you have defined, then you are best using jQuery like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('table#tab tr').click(function() {
        var firstTd = $(this).find("td:first");
        console.log(firstTd); // log it so you can see it.
    });
);
```

Then using the `firstTd` variable you can do `firstTd.text()` for the text value, or `firstTd.html()` for the full HTML contents of it.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your HTML**

```
<table id="tab">
    <tr>
        <td>Sachin</td>
        <td>Yuvraj</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Virat</td>
        <td>Gautam</td>              
    </tr>
</table>
```

**The Following Script will give you Value of Each Cell on Click**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#tab').click(function (event) {
    alert($(event.target).html());
   });
});
```

**The Following Script will give First Column Value on Clicking Row (Your Question)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#tab tr').on('click',function() {
    alert($(this).find('td:first').text());
  });
});
```

Check out the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vijaysarin/7dUfZ/23/)